# UIPageViewController transition allowing

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm developing an application. The core of it is `UIViewController` with Path-like style (swiping left and right causes the view moving and right- and left- controllers appearing)
So on the central (root) viewController I'm using `UIPageViewController`.
I init it like this

```
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
        initWithTransitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll 
          navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal 
                        options: @{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: @30}];
```

I know that I cant find any `UIGestureRecognizer`'s of `UIPageViewController` while using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.
The problem I faced is: when my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which is handling my left and right swipes are active, it does what I suppose - left and right menus became on the screen, but in this moment

> UIPageViewController

scrolls the pages.

So I want to block this scrolling and page transition in the `UIPageViewController` while my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` handles menus appearing.

In the other words - is there any way to prevent page transition of `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Why are you overlaying a UIPanGestureRecognizer on a UIPageViewController in the first place?  Are your 'users' having trouble finding the menus (they end up 'missing' which cases the page to scroll accidentally)?

Comment: You can move menus only by two fingers swiping, this UIPanGestureRecognizer is in rootViewController. UIPageViewController's view is only subview of it and it's a childViewController also.
The perfect variant is to allow scroll pages only by one finger swiping.